# resolving complex entity model to flat model view using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I want to create a map for a somewhat complex entity model to a flattened view Model

My entity model is like so

```
cbItems 
    has many cbItemsContent
            has many cbRegulators
```

so my viewmodels are like so

for cbItems:

```
public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public ItemViewModel()
        {
            this.CbItemsContents = new HashSet<ItemContentViewModel>();
        }

        public int ItemID { get; set; }
         ...... 
        public virtual ICollection<ItemContentViewModel> CbItemsContents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

for cbItemsContent:

```
public class ItemContentViewModel
    {

        public int ItemContentID { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        ....
        public ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel RegulatedBy { get; set; }

    }
}
```

for cbRegulators:

```
public class ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel
    {
        public int ItemContentId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<int> RegulatorIds { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I  had hoped it would be as easy as this:

```
config.CreateMap<CbItem, ItemViewModel>();
            config.CreateMap<CbItemsContent, ItemContentViewModel>()
                     .ForMember(dest => dest.RegulatedBy.ItemContentId,
                         m => m.MapFrom(src => src.GenericID))
                     .ForMember(dest => dest.RegulatedBy.RegulatorIds,
                         n => n.MapFrom(src => src.cbItemsContentRegulators.Select(q => q.cbRegulator.RegulatorId)));
```

from teh following query:

```
ItemViewModel item = 
_context.cbItems.Where(u => u.ItemId = id)
.ProjectTo<ItemViewModel>()
.first();
```

But this results in an error:

> Expression 'dest => dest.RegulatedBy.ItemContentId' must resolve to
>   top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom
>   resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead. Parameter
>   name: lambdaExpression

HOw can I achieve my desired model layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rabban probably means something like this:

```
config.CreateMap<CbItemsContent, ItemContentViewModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.RegulatedBy, o => o.MapFrom(src => src));

config.CreateMap<CbItemsContent, ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemContentId, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.GenericID))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.RegulatorIds, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.cbItemsContentRegulators.Select(q => q.cbRegulator.RegulatorId)));
```

Comment: Thats practically what I had, I was missing the '.ForMember(dest => dest.RegulatedBy, o => o.MapFrom(src => src));' for the first Map. Im not sure I understand what is happening in that line, can you shed any light?  Im not sure what REgulatedBy is being mapped to with (src=>src)

Comment: it basically tells AutoMapper that RegulatedBy (meaning type `ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel`) will be mapped from the source (meaning `CbItemsContent`), so it will then look for a mapping from `CbItemsContent` to `ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel` - which is defined below

Answer (score 1):

You have to map `ItemContentRegulatorsViewModel`, then you don't need to set it from the ViewModel above.